# How to exclude some directories from SVN repository during checkout

Tags: svn, batch-file

I am writing a script to checkout data from an SVN repository. The URL is

http://subversion-practice.sweng.xyz.com/cvn/repos/ps/passport

There is a folder under passport on this non-local URL which I need to exclude from checkout viz. `Data_backup` (Folder name to be excluded).

SVN checkout command used is

```
svn checkout --username ab230141 --password Table717 http://subversion-practice.sweng.xyz.com/cvn/repos/ps/passport >> C:/svn_log.log 2>&1
```

Can someone please help with the commands I could use for this ?

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html). You need `svn checkout --depth empty` followed by few `svn update --set-depth infinity` commands for the children. It's pretty well explained in the linked manual. I guess the deeper the excluded folder is in the tree, the more update commands you need.

Alternatively you can first checkout the whole tree and then run `svn update --set-depth exclude` for the folder you want to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Sparse Directories. I had heard the name of the feature before, but I'd wouldn't have guessed it meant a subset of the hierarchy.

Comment: The exclude tip was very helpful when there were a few directories I wanted to exclude in a large hierarchy.